# Issue with IE8 and IE9 in Windows7: Does not work to call function after load()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://domain/functionfile.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var jQ110 = $.noConflict(true);   
jQ110(function ($) {
if ($( "#element20-input" ).length>0) {
    $( "#element20-input" ).load( 
    "https://domain/page #elementwidget-input", function() {    
        widgetfrontend(248);
    });
}
});
</script>
```

**html**

```
<div id="element20-input">Loading...</div>
<div id="elementwidget-result">Loading...</div>
```

Above works fine in Safari, Opera, Firefox, Chrome etc and in IE9+ but not in IE8. The console throws and "`Object expected`" at line (when using IE8):

```
widgetfrontend(248);
```

`widgetfrontend` function is defined in `https://domain/functionfile.js`like this:

```
function widgetfrontend( mun_id ) {
    alert( mun_id );
}
```

Why is the error given? Isn't the javascript loaded correctly or what? Why is that?

**UPDATE**

Using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

I'm using cross domain scripting. Yes, allow access origin etc is set on server, so that works.

Comment: Try loading your script with jQuery's $.getScript("https://domain/functionfile.js")

Comment: I think the more important question is: Why do you need to support IE8? ;)

Comment: @ThiefMaster - because they pay for it to work! :-)

Comment: True that. IE < 9 is a nightmare. Tell them to update.

Comment: It's also between different domains. Sorry I forgot to mention that in the question.

Comment: at which line specifically? in which file? which line is that in the above code?

Comment: @KevinB - I wrote that? At widgetfrontend(248);

Comment: that doesn't make much sense. please debug a bit more around that area.

Comment: @KevinB - the first javascript and html is one file (html file). The js file https://domain/functionfile.js is on another domain. Why does it matter which row it is on? What does not make sense?

Comment: the error you are getting doesn't make sense. (which isn't your fault, IE8 gives crap error messages). You'll have to debug around that part of the code to see why it's throwing that error.

Comment: @KevinB - but that's my point. That was my question .Why is the error given? :-) I thought someone might know why. I'm not looking for someone to solve it, but I justed wanted some pointer what to look for. Now I understand that widgetfrontend() is not defined when try to call that function in IE8/IE9. IE9 gives error widgetfrontend() is undefined. In all other browsers it is defined.

Comment: Good, we're getting somewhere then. is this a typo? `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://domain/functionfile.js"</script>`

Comment: @KevinB - no it's not a typo? domain is the other domain.

Comment: @KevinB  - aha yes. fixed that (tired yesterday)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone stumble upon this question. IE8 and IE9 uses XDomainRequest (Microsofts own handling of responses in ajax calls). When using SSL XDomainRequest only works if both domains has SSL.

**More detailed info here:**
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds/